# Assign to generic function parameter in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

I would like to use a generic function as an parameter. However, I can't find how to instanciate such a type. Here's a simple example, that I would expect to work:

```js
function foo(a: number, f: <U>(a: number) => U) {
    f(a) // removed the return to make the example simpler
}
function bar(a: number) : number {
    return 2*a
}
foo(8, bar);
```

Thing is, I get this error:

> Argument of type '(a: number) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: number) => U'.
> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'U'.
> 'U' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'number'.

The last part seems especially odd to me, since U shouldn't be anything other than a number in this case. How do I instanciate U as a number? Is there a specific syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here but moving `U` to the front will fix this problem:

```
function foo<U>(a: number, f: (a: number) => U) {
    return f(a) 
}
function bar(a: number) : number {
    return 2*a
}
foo(8, bar);
```

If you want to introduce generic types in a function declaration you should put them right after the function name. When the function is called TypeScript will then try to infer the correct types.